# Why is the output of imsubtract() double?

Tags: image, matlab

I was doing some morphological operations on images when I got this error:

> Function imlincomb expected its array input arguments (A1, A2, ...) to
>   have the same class.

It was given in the `imsubtract()` function where one of the inputs was the output of another subtraction. I checked the Matlab docs and found this explanation for `Z = imsubtract(X,Y)`: (emphasis is mine)

> The array returned, Z, has the same size and class as X **unless X is logical, in which case Z is double.**

Why should in the case of logical input X, the output be **double**?!

It doesn't make sense at all. Specially, when the 2 input arguments are both *logical* and considering this function is mostly (if not always) used for images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 possible values (and boolean can only capture 2 values):

- `0 (true-true, false-false)`
- `1 (true-false)`
- `-1 (false-true)`

To see that, try:

```
>> imsubtract([true,true,false,false],[true,false,true,false])

ans =

     0     1    -1     0
```

If you want something amenable to further logical processing, call boolean:

```
>> boolean(imsubtract([true,true,false,false],[true,false,true,false]))

ans =

     0     1     1     0
```

Comment: So basically you're saying the *double* output is because of the negative values?

Comment: @Mahm00d im saying that the fact that you need 3 states precludes a boolean output.  They chose double.  But you have to decide how to handle `true-false` and `false-true`.  The way matlab does it, it preserves expectations (true=1, false=0) without losing information (if they just did true in the case of `false-true`, you wouldn't be able to distinguish `false-true` from `true-false`)

Comment: My problem is why `false-true` shouldn't be `false` (thus no need for 3rd state)? It makes sense in working with images and interestingly, Matlab's example of this function in the case of `uint8` clearly states: "Subtract two uint8 arrays. Note that negative results are rounded to 0."

Comment: If `false-true` were false, then you are specifically looking for the case `true-false = true, everything else is false`, which you can do as `x-y>0`